# Coding Style - Passing method as Parameter

Tags: c#, coding-style

I have very a basic question. I have a `MethodB` returning `Integer`. I have a `MethodA` where I want to pass the value retrieved from `MethodB`.

Is it a right way (the coding style, not the syntax) to pass `MethodB` to `MethodA` as mentioned below?

```
MethodA(MethodB());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not passing the method 'MethodB' but the value that it returns.
In fact, your code is equivalent to:

```
int i = MethodB();
MethodA(i);
```

It's perfectly ok to do it, as long as your code remains readable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - MethodB will be called first and return a value which will then be used as the parameter for the call to MethodA

Answer (score 2):

It's fine but reads poorly and you can't easily set a breakpoint on MethodB's return. I strongly prefer splitting it up:

```
 var bResult = MethodB();
 MethodA(bResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's okay. In fact I'd say it's a great idea, especially if the method names are appropriate.

```
displayName(getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample is completely valid.  The returned value of `MethodB` is what will be passed into `MethodA`.